# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'checked' of null - html checkbox toggle

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an error when attempting to run a function once a checkbox is being checked. The above error appears consistently each time I am attempting to run it. Heres the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header_container">
            <h1>Trivia Quiz</h1>
            <p>Welcome to the Trivia Quiz 2020!</p>
            <p>The aim of the game is to get as many questions correct as possible!<br> The topics range from film to geography, so good luck!</p>
            <div class="header_settings" id="header_settings">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="TimeToggle()">
                <label for="TimeToggle">Time Limit</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="Timer" name="Timer" placeholder="Seconds" id="header_input">
            </div>
            <button>Start</button>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

And Javascript (stored externally, linked in the head of the HTML document.):

```
var header_input = document.getElementById("header_input");
var header_settings = document.getElementById("header_settings");
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

function TimeToggle() {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        header_settings.style.height = "3%";
        setTimeout(function () {
            header_input.style.display = "none";
        }, 500);
    } else {
        header_settings.style.height = "10%";
        setTimeout(function () {
            header_input.style.display = "block";
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

The code is intended to toggle the height of the div named "header_settings", and the display setting of the input named "header_input" depending on whether the checkbox is checked.

I would appreciate any pointers regarding how this is not working, I have tried a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: You can not have two `id's` in one input - Also use an `onchange` function instead of aan `onclick`.

Comment: I have since corrected both issues mentioned above, however I am still getting the same error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at TimeToggle (script.js:37)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (index.html:26)"

Comment: @SphenX have you tried the answer I posted below? Are you ensuring the document has loaded before you try getting those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do ? You can use an `onchange` function and pass `this` as an `argument` and check if in your toggle function if input is checked or unchecked.

Also, you have had two `id` selectors on your input which is not possible.

In addition, please ensure that your `scripts.js` is loading just added before the `</body>` end tag

Add this code as your **HTML** input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="TimeToggle(this)">
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function TimeToggle(el) {
  var header_input = document.getElementById("header_input");
  var header_settings = document.getElementById("header_settings");
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
  if (el.checked) {
    header_settings.style.height = '50px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      header_input.style.display = "none";
    }, 500);
  } else {
    header_settings.style.height = '100px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      header_input.style.display = "block";
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header_container">
      <h1>Trivia Quiz</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the Trivia Quiz 2020!</p>
      <p>The aim of the game is to get as many questions correct as possible!<br> The topics range from film to geography, so good luck!</p>
      <div class="header_settings" id="header_settings">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="TimeToggle(this)">
        <label for="TimeToggle">Time Limit</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Timer" placeholder="Seconds" id="header_input">
      </div>
      <button>Start</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a very common one. You are trying to get the html elements using `document.get...` before the DOM has loaded. You need to wrap those document fetches in the onload listener for the window:

```javascript
let checkbox;
window.onload = function() {
  checkbox = document.getElementById();
};

function TimeToggle() {//...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the external JS to at the end. Just before`</body>`. And your problem will be solved.

Somewhat like

```
<body>
<!--Your HTML content here-->
<script src = "External Js.js"></script>
</body>
```